# Passing data to HTML from PHP

Tags: javascript, php, html

i'm seeking an assist on the following problem.

Problem : I'm facing a trouble where the user type in the information in the PHP form , it doesn't save and store the information in another HTML file.

PHP:

```
<?php
$a= $_POST['name'];
$b= $_POST['age'];

?>
```

HTML :

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>

<input type="hidden" name="name" value="<?php echo $name ?>">
<input type="hidden" name="age"  value="<?php echo $age ?>">
```

Problem is when I check the page , the value is empty.
Anyone know what's the problem?

Comment: ...Because you're storing the name in `$a`, not `$name`?

Comment: Does your form send data via `POST` or `GET`? Also check variable`s names

Comment: Is your php and html code in the same file? It should be one `.php` file.

Comment: Also i have just noticed you are echoing out different variables to what you have set in the PHP. Try setting them as the same

Comment: It appears your `inputs` are in the `head` of your html instead of the `body`.

Answer (score 0):

If this is the actual code the problem is quote obvious: you are setting the variables `$a` and `$b` but reading from the undefined variables `$name` and `$age`. Fix it in the setting part:

```
<?php
$name = $_POST['name'];
$age = $_POST['age'];
?>
```

Comment: But they're two different page

Comment: Why is that so? Does your PHP script redirect to the HTML page upon completion? Why didn't you merge both?

Answer (score 0):

What do you expect `$name` and `$age` to have as a value?

First thing you could do is turn on error_reporting you'll get an undefined variable error

```
error_reporting(E_ALL);
```

To fix your code you should instead of echoing `$name` and `$age` echo `$a` and `$b`

Answer (score 0):

use The same variables which you are storing while prnting in html

```
<?php
$a= $_POST['name'];
$b= $_POST['age'];

?>

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>

<input type="hidden" name="name" value="<?php echo $a ?>">
<input type="hidden" name="age"  value="<?php echo $b ?>">
```

Comment: But they're two different page

Answer (score 0):

Lets say you have First form

i made the dummy form just to show you how it can be done.

```
<?php
error_reporting($level=NULL);

?>



<form action="new.php" method="post">
    <input type="text" name="name" value="<?php echo $_SESSION['name']?>">
    <input type="text" name="age"  value="<?php echo $_SESSION['age']?>">
       <input type="submit" name="submit">

</form>
```

Now it will direct you to. new.php

The code for new php is This

```
<?php


session_start();
if(isset($_POST['submit']))
{
    $_SESSION['name']=$_POST['name'];
    $_SESSION['age']=$_POST['age'];

}
```

I created one more file. instead of using hidden i used disabled. if you want you can use hidden value as well but in order to get the hidden value you need to see the source code. which you can get by clicking right click. Thanks i used disable so you can see this in action.

i gave this file name form.php you can give any name. Thanks

```
<?php



session_start();
?>
<form action="new.php" method="post">
    <input type="text" name="name" value="" disabled>
<input type="text" name="age"  value="<?php echo $_SESSION['name']; ?>" disabled>
</form>
```

One last important point now you have access to $_session['name']; and $_session['age']; where you want. you just have to include session start at the top. and you can display these variable where ever you like.

To see this in action fill some dummy value click submit. run the both form again you will find your value there. Thanks